# DOMException when trying to change value of textarea

Tags: angular, data-binding

This is my html part:

```
 <textarea
   formControlName="post-content" 
   (keyup)="check(myText)"
   [(ngModel)]="myText">
 </textarea>
```

and my check function be like

```
checkText(text) {
        // cannot change the value of (myText)
        this.myText = something;
}
```

I got this error

```
DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement' This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

I tried to replace the textarea with input, but same problem. I tried also to remove ngModel which the problem releated to it and put [value] directive instead, it worked but I cannot remove ngModel I need it.

Comment: I don't think your error is related to the textarea

Comment: @Carsten That's right because I replace it with input but still not working, I'm confused why I can't change the value as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved, the real problem was in `formControlName="post-content"`, I don't know what exactly causes but I'm using `post-content` alot, when I change the name to `post-content-text` it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Few Mistakes in your code

- `checkText` is your method in controller side but you are calling `check`
- `something` is not declared.
- why to pass myText from  `check(myText)` instead  simply get using `this.myText`

  ```
  <textarea
   (keyup)="checkText(myText)"
   [(ngModel)]="myText">
  </textarea>

  checkText(text) {
   this.myText = 'something text';
  }
  ```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nprp86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Sorry I changed it to checkText in my code but forget to replace it here, I tried but same problem.

Comment: NP, But working fine in my  example, have you checked?